# ASP.NET Printing Page

Tags: asp.net

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="DemoReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reports_DemoReport" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
              <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
        <script  type="text/javascript">
        function CallPrint(strid) {
            var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
            var strOldOne = prtContent.innerHTML;
            var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=600,height=400,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
            WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
            WinPrint.document.close();
            WinPrint.focus();
            WinPrint.print();
            WinPrint.close();
        }
</script>
        <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Search Date Wise</legend>
            <table class="auto-style1">
                <tr>

                    <td>From Date</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFromDate" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                        &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgFromDate" ImageUrl="~/_images/Calendar.gif" AlternateText="FromDate" />
                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="dtpFromDate" runat="server" CssClass=" cal_Theme1" TargetControlID="txtFromDate"
                            Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgFromDate" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" />
                    </td>
                    <td>To Date</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtToDate" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                        &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgTodate" ImageUrl="~/_images/Calendar.gif" AlternateText="ToDate" />
                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" CssClass=" cal_Theme1" TargetControlID="txtToDate"
                            Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgTodate" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" />
                    </td>

                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnGO" Text="GO" runat="server" Width="80px" OnClick="btnGO_Click" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" Width="80px" OnClientClick="CallPrint('printDIV');" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

        <div id="printDIV">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Complain Histroy</legend>

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="1250px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellSpacing="2">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
           <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <%#Eval("CurrentDate") %>
                   </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
               </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Superviser" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <%#Eval("SUPERVISER") %>
                   </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
               </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QuarterNo" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <%#Eval("QNUMBER") %>
                   </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
               </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AcknowledgementKey" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <%#Eval(" ACKEY") %>
                   </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
               </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ComplainKey" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <%#Eval("COMPKEY") %>
                   </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
               </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <%#Eval("STATUS") %>
                   </ItemTemplate>

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
               </asp:TemplateField>

           </Columns>

                 </asp:GridView>
        </fieldset>
    </div>



</asp:Content>
```

I have to print only the grid view that is on the page , Printing is working fine but I want to generate dynamic header/footer on the print page.
How I can achieve that. I am generally from java back ground so please if you are writing code make it less complicated. 
Thanks for your time consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like follows

```
var prinText="hereaderhtml";
printText+=prtContent.innerHTML;
printText+="footerhtml";
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
```